# Why I can not access Axis2 service at localhost?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I am developing a Web Service project using axis2, tomcat and eclipse.
I download axis2 war package and drop it to tomcat/webapps, then I start tomcat , I can access tomcat at http://localhost:8080, but failed to access http://localhost:8080/axis2,please tell me what the problem might be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set TOMCAT_HOME environment variable, Set the value to top level directory of your Tomcat install (e.g. D:\programs\apache-tomcat-6.0.29)

Answer (score 0):

what error you are receiving in logs and what version of tomcat using. 
If no error is there , please check , the default web services included with Axis2 will be available by visiting http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ 
For reference : http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html